# Python - angle brackets in command line arguments

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

How do I pass angle brackets `<` and `>` as command line arguments to my Python program?

For example:

`python main.py <div>HelloWorld<div>`

Currently it is giving me an error because the terminal is interpreting *<* and *>* as redirects.

I know that wrapping with quotes will work - like:

`python main.py "<div>HelloWorld<div>"`

Is there anyway to make this work without quotes?

Comment: Quoting is the correct way to accomplish this. Why not do so?

Comment: Why do you think `"<div>HelloWorld<div>"` is problematic? Did you test this?

Comment: You *can* use slashes instead, but why would you *want* to? Quoting is perfectly fine & readable.

Comment: I don't think its problematic, but if there is a way to do the argument edits in main.py I would prefer it

Comment: The problem is that `<` and `>` are *shell* metacharacters, and will be interpreted *before* your program even runs -- so they must be escaped. There's nothing you can do in `main.py` to solve this.

Comment: There's no way to fix this in main.py because the problem occurs before it even arrives at main.py. As costaparas said, this is handled by the shell.

Comment: Look at `sys.argv` to see what `argparse` has to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the special characters:

```sh
python main.py \<div\>HelloWorld\<div\>
```

Others have suggested wrapping the argument in quotes, which is much more readable and simpler IMHO.